# MacBook as a handsfree headset

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, android

Is there any way how to use laptop as a hands-free "headset" for my Android phone via Bluetooth?

Actually it's very nice to answer on calls directly from computer.

I have tried BluePhoneElite2 for that, but it is a bit slow. I'm thinking that for just a hands free headset, I should be able to use Snow Leopard without any additional software.

I have connected my phone and laptop over Bluetooth already, but what should I do to receive calls on the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X does not natively support the bluetooth headset [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile), which is what a bluetooth device needs to support in order to act as a hands free device.

BluePhoneElite2 loads a special driver onto select phones that gets around this - likely by using a different bluetooth profile to deliver audio and phone actions.

There is currently no native solution in any version of OS X.

Comment: Too bad, i'm thinking that it's too bad :( Why company who did phone won't think about it :( very strange.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late, but as of today it can be done with this application http://www.getdialogue.com/

With that application a pc running OS X can be used as a Bluetooth handsfree headset for ones mobile phone. Allowing one to originate and answer calls without reaching for the phone and then have the audio through the speaker and microphone of the PC or an attacted headset.

Comment: I'm interested as to why this has -1 vote. It seems like a perfect solution to the problem.