# Is there a Mac equivalent to Windows' Phone Link for use with Android?

Tags: macos, big-sur, android

I have an Android phone and I use Windows 11 at home.  I really like the Phone Link for Windows, and I am hoping there is something similar for the Mac I use at work, which runs Big Sur.  I know that it's possible to connect an iPhone to a Mac and take calls from the iPhone through the Mac, but is there something similar for Android?  Thanks!

CLARIFICATION: The big thing I would like to do is be able to make calls on my Android phone from the Mac.

Comment: You’re going to have to help us out a bit here… What does Phone Link do?  Do you want to make calls, transfer files, or something else?

Comment: @Allan The big thing is I would like to make calls through the Mac.

Comment: See if this can help you out.  Andriod calling isn’t a big topic here.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55723/119271

Comment: @Allan I looked at that but the company that makes the software in question appears to be defunct.  I am hoping there is something new?

Comment: Let's leave this up to see if there's a solution out there from using the Mac as a speakerphone/headset device to actually transfering calls.  I unfortunately don't have any Android devices to test with.

Comment: [This thread](https://twitter.com/MishaalRahman/status/1643672185276440593) hints at CallControl and StreamingCall APIs coming to Android 14 later this year. The researcher claims it will be internal to Android, but I'd venture to guess someone will take advantage of that to develop something for the use case described here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** see bold text

**Natively**, [this feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209456) is **exclusive to the Apple ecosystem.** It uses something known as [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689#handoff) as part of [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681), which inherently requires iOS and macOS.

AirDroid is a popular third-party app that implements answering cellular calls from a computer (via web UI), but "[technical restrictions](https://help.airdroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007483153)" prevent the computer from acting as a microphone. I doubt they would object to supporting this feature if it were straightforward to implement. *It is* programmatically doable (see [Connecton](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/connecton/id1497000705)), but none have managed to do a decent job at an affordable price yet.

**That being said**, the closest I can think of to replicate this functionality would be [**Google Voice**](https://voice.google.com). It is essentially **a virtual phone number with cross-platform (web) access to calling and messaging** at fairly standard [rates](https://voice.google.com/rates). The caveat is of course... are you willing to trust Google (in addition to, and to the same extent as, Apple) with your data?

Comment: Google Voice would require using a different phone number. It's also been on life support for years and could be discontinued by Google at any time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source program that does this, to a degree. You install the app on your phone and also on your computer, manually pair them, select what features you want, and it should work more or less okay whenever both devices are on the same wifi. It's not nearly polished, but it does do the job. You can see mobile notifications on the desktop, send files like AirDrop, and a lot more.

It is called [KDE connect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/download.html), and you can download it for your phone from the playstore, and for your Mac, PC, or other supported platforms.